# Rails ActiveSupport:Concern that raises exception when included if the model doesn't respond_to? some methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I'm coding a Rails Concern that will be added to multiple models. For extra safety, I want to make sure that all models that this concern is included in responds to some instance methods. Call it a contract if you want.

Anyway, here's the code I expected to work:

```rb
module SomeConcern

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    raise("The model has to respond to some_instance_method") if !self.method_defined?(:some_instance_method)

  end

end
```

However, this exception always gets raised.

- Concerns are generally (due to styleguides) included at the top of the model; however, at that point, we haven't reached the `def` call in the model yet, so the instance method isn't defined yet.
- Even if we include the concern at the very bottom of the model (which is something I really wish I could avoid for a better developer experience), I noticed that if `some_instance_method` is actually a column name, it will only respond `true` to `method_defined?` if I instantiate the model beforehand.

With a `binding.pry` inside the `included` block, this happens:

```rb
self.method_defined?(:some_column_name)
=> false

self.new

self.method_defined?(:some_column_name)
=> true
```

So, giving all these, what is the best way to raise an exception, when the concern is included in the Model, to make sure that one instance of that model actually responds to some methods I want to check?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a default `some_instance_method` in `SomeConcern`, which `raise` error when your call it if you don't have a method with same name in `SomeModal`:

```rb
module SomeConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def some_instance_method
    raise("The model has to respond to some_instance_method")
  end
end

class SomeModal
  include SomeConcern

  def some_instance_method
    do_the_work
  end
end
```